# Access websites that are restricted in my country using a secure VPN Client

Tags: gratis, windows-7, internet, vpn

Im looking for a lightweight and easy to use VPN software solution that can help you browse the web securely and access websites that are restricted in my country in other words **(Bypass internet censorship)**

- Runs on windows 7
- Easy installation :)
- Expecting to use the VPN service for free,and its obvious that they would restrict data transfer amount I would be more happy at-least if the VPN service provides 2GB of data transfer per month
- of course it should be sercure VPN service !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a VPN application called [Hide.me](https://hide.me/en/) I Installed in my machine and this works like a charm

**Hide.me Features:**

[image]
[image]

**Free plan: 1 connection limited to 2 servers, 2 GB data transfer, bandwidth on a “best effort” basis – meaning you get what’s left over from the paying clients, and no OpenVPN.**

***Hide.me does not keep any log-files – which really sets them apart from the other big VPN services.***

[image]

Where I found the application [Bestvpnproviders.net](http://www.bestvpnproviders.net/provider/hide-me/)

Answer (score 5):

[Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) should suffice to bypass most cases of country-based internet censorship. It's though not really a VPN in the strict meaning, but it should fulfill all your other requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You should also look at the [Java Anonymizing Proxy](http://anon.inf.tu-dresden.de/index_en.html) which is free, from the technical university at Dresden.

Basically, you run a Java program on your PC which acts as a local proxy for your browser and encrypts all URLs so that your ISP can't see them and sends them to the JAP server which fetches the page & returns to you.

I can't remember if the page contents are encrypted in transmission.

I would check that and post some quotes from their website, but, ironically, I am at work and my company's server won't let me access it.

**Edit:**

> Each mix carries out cryptographic operations on the message so that the JAP-encrypted data is only readable when it's gone through the proper mixes in the proper order. That way it's [e]nsured, that an eavesdropper either only receives unreadable (encrypted) data or can no longer determine the sender.

[Source of quote](http://anon.inf.tu-dresden.de/desc/desc_anon_en.html)

Answer (score 2):

[cyberghostvpn.com](http://cyberghostvpn.com) it is secure, you can check the about page, the free version offer unlimited bandwidth in theory, but disconnects every 2 hours, just reconnect no big deal. Also few servers for the free version. easy to install and runs on windows. Bypass internet censorship? you bet.

[tunnelbear.com](https://www.tunnelbear.com/) never used it so won't write anything about it but heard it's good, my vote goes for cyberghost any day.

TOR is too damn slow and you can't stream anything, just so you know. And proxies can be detected, for instance you can't use spotify in Lebanon using a proxy, but you can using a VPN.

Comment: Sounds perfect will try cyberghostvpn definitely  !

Answer (score 2):

Btw, although I recommended JAP, I personally pay for [BTguard](https://btguard.com/) which let's me do all that you ask for, plus download torrents. All untraceable, end to end encrypted with no records kept.

Once again, I am behind my company's server so can't, alas, access the page to copy/paste the best parts (now, if only I had BTguard installed on my office PC ...)

---

[update]

- Simple download & install No records of usage stored 256-bit AES
- encryption Unlimited download speeds, 10Gbit servers VPN includes
- OpenVPN & PPTP Servers in Canada, Europe and Asia

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I love [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/), so XTaran's recommendation is solid, and I strongly recommend you consider using the [TOR browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en), or some configuration that uses TOR. Another alternative to TOR (which is *not* as secure as the TOR browser) is to install [Vidalia Bridge Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) and configure your browser(s) to use the bridge as a proxy. I use Google Chrome and I use a great plugin, [Quick & Dirty Proxy Flipper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/quick-dirty-proxy-flipper/lbhdjpmomigdcfkidmimojhnoacaffcg?hl=en), because it makes it simple to switch between your normal connection and your Vidalia bridge.

I had not heard of the JAP project mentioned by Mawg, but after looking at the documentation, the ideas in it are brilliant, so it is also worth considering.

If, however, you still want another option, one this is technically a VPN, then [TunnelBear](https://www.tunnelbear.com/) is a decent option. I used it for a little while. It was easy to install and extremely simple to use. The only reason I stopped using it was because TOR met my needs.

Answer (score 1):

**[Hola](https://hola.org/)** works just fine. You can use it as a Chrome plugin.

Comment: Hola is generally considered to be bad news. Just do a search for it. See, for example, https://www.vpnmentor.com/reviews/hola-vpn/, which says in part "Technically, Hola is not a VPN provider, but a poorly secured botnet. The Hola community-powered peer-to-peer network claims to provide it's users with secure and anonymous internet traffic. However, because it doesn't use its own servers, but rather routes traffic through peer nodes provided by their 55 million users..."

Answer (score 0):

NordVPN is not for free. But cheap price and easy to install. As for me, fast connection.  But Tor is good too. Although everyone recommend, I think that your internet connection is slow.